# How do I export audio in a video that is purposefully loud and distorted? (VSE)

Tags: rendering, export, video-sequence-editor, audio, encoding

I am editing a video in Blender's Video Sequence Editor (VSE) and I have a lot of audio that is loud, distorted, and clipping. This is intentional.

However, when I render my final video, all the clipping audio is simply replaced with normal audio and some random beeps.

I am exporting into MPEG-4 with H.264 and AAC audio.

How do I get Blender to not curb my audio so it exports it loud and distorted?

EDIT: Yes, I am trying to make earrape videos with Blender...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! It turns out that I need to set the audio codec to MP3, ***NOT*** AAC.

Comment: This is fascinating. Thanks for figuring it out.