# VSE: audio 'now' not rendering properly - clipping/missing/distorted (edited)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

2018-03-25: As suggested in the comments inserting the project as a scene strip in a new scene tab allows you to adjust the mastervolume of the entire scene like in render options. You can then mixdown. Mixdown did not skip any keyframed audio clips or distort/clip using this method. seems to be the best workaround atm in the ui. I'm going to be capturing in audacity though instead I think, just cause it feels more like what I edited that way.

2018-03-24 edit: Sent bug report for the audio clipping problem, unable to produce .blend sample of the keyframed audio missing at this time.

2018-03-24 edit upload:
[image]
This is of the first problem where 1 strip is set to the default 1.0, the 2nd at 10.0. Then both are ontop of eachother. Point is: if you mixdown this and put it in audacity you'll see mixdown clips the higher volume one, how to not do that...
I couldn't reproduce and upload a copy of the keyframed audio skipping/notplaying. oR I could, but i couldn't upload it.

*2018-03-022 re-edited:*

**What I hear on playback in the vse is now different from what I get after I render.**

When I mixdown just audio, setting accuracy to 1 (normal setting creates 'more' distortions), the waveform output is clearly clipping when viewed in audacity compared to the waveform of the captured playback in the vse (aka mixdown is amplifying so much it distorts; See picture 1). There are also missing audio strips, potentially due to the clipping.
Having audio strips set to low values, in their individual n-tab, like making the 1.0 value the midrange of my audio (the default), makes it avoid clipping. For example I had a strip set to 10.0, doing mixdown it was distorted and horrible sounding like in picture1. Upon changing the value to 1.0 tho, it sounded the same way as it did when I captured it in the vse playback via audacity. I also couldn't find any missing strips so far via this method. The only difference was the waveform was amplified a bit differently (aka a bit quieter), but this can be fixed in audacity if necessary.

*VSE playback is the first waveform (sounds great). Mixdown in .wav/.flac is the 2nd/third waveforms (loud/distorted)*
[image: figure1]

**Now the other route to getting audio rendered...**
When I render audio alongside video (normally), the problems are similar to the mixdown, only I can set the master volume lower (the bar in audio options that is set to 1.0 by default; I set it to 0.1) and the waveform output doesn't clip but everything is really quiet and you have to turn ur volume up to hear normal levels (the output is NOT clipping tho, which is good). Okay...so far so good. 
However:

**1.** I don't know what amplification/volume its rendering at in comparison to what I hear on playback in the vse. Trial and error required to get a grasp. So I don't know what value to set the mastervolume to perfectly avoid clipping while keeping the volume as high as possible.

**2.** Some audio strips do not render at all for some reason regardless of master volume settings. Those with keyframes specifically. Some with keyframes render fine though. Rendering "just" (or smaller sections, to the extent I don't know) the specific section with the keyframed audio pieces tho solves the problem for some reason.

**So based on this the following workarounds can be done:**

**Workaround 1:**
I can playback everything in the vse, and capture it using audacity and use that as my audio file. In the image below I deleted EVERYTHING except my audio strips so playback would be smooth (even if I set it to av-sync, audio can stutter with too much stuff in the vse). **Infact this is a good summation of the problem and what I need to do:**

***I need to mix all this audio down so it isn't clipping/distorting/missing: problem is it sounds fine as is in the vse playback, but after rendered it is infact clipping/missing/distorting audio strips.***

[image]

**Workaround 2:**
If I go in and lower the strip volume options individually so they are all lower values (I have to try to make the mid range around the 1.0 volume values). Then this enables me to mixdown, thus creating a version that doesn't have the clipping and doesn't have missing strips (as far as I can tell anyways). However this is a ton of work given the project is 25 mins of many many audio strips, to be individually reset/mastered (see picture above). Plus I still don't know what level of amplification mixdown is applying, so i can only make a copy of an amplification that doesn't clip that will need to be amplified in audacity afterwards (which isn't that hard to do).

**Workaround 3:**
Divide the 25 mins up into 60 second intervals, and render the video/audio together out bit by bit then reform and do a final render. Very lengthy process though and no guarantee it will work in 60 second intervals, might have to do less.

**Closing thoughts:**
If there was a method of changing the mixdown volume/amplification (to prevent it from going so loud its clipping)....that would create a solution and I could just mixdown audio and video separate and recombine later. I just want the thing that plays in my vse....to sound the same as the thing it renders out as. Audio mixdown seems to offer the only solution I can find in blender's immediate ui, since normal render is missing strips when I render more than small portions. But this will require, for future projects, making sure my volume is super high when working in the blender VSE, to ensure I avoid clipping. I would then use audacity to finetune the amplification/volume levels so the mid range is the same as other videos.

*Regardless I need blender to do apply "What you see/hear is what you get" in order to continue using it as a video editor for anything involving more than singular audio strips. So is this a bug I won't have to deal with again or a limitation? I guess is the future question.*

Comment: changing the accuracy seems to help. I set the accuracy to 1 and it was good for a small segment. Then I set it to just under 2000 and it clipped and went bad for alot of it like the problem originally. So I'll try mixing down the entire thing with 1 accuracy. I don't know what that means or does tho....can't find anything in the online manual of use. I heard you can mixdown audio and video in vlc so ill try that mbe, render with no audio....mixdown...then combine in vlc? Is there a better program to combine audio and video files?

Comment: Consider transcoding the media to a more blender friendly format?

Comment: i don't understand any of that. Can you elaborate? what would be a blender friendly format? most of the audio strips r .wav 16, some are mp3

Comment: Oh I thought that you were using audio from video files, like mp4. They can be troublesome as the frame rate is calculated differently for video than for audio (technically audio uses sample rate not frame rate) and they can get a bit muddled. I think your best bet is to try accuracy. It will spend more time converting off sample rate media to your project settings.

Comment: ya these are all separate audio files I subbed in, aka I had VA do them and I sub them as strips on the video frames and manually sync. Do you know what the difference between the other options are tho? for .wav it has signed and floating point...idk what the difference is. what is better quality? .flac only has up to S24. wav has up to F64. which would be better to try for the entire 30 mins of audio clips? Most of the audio strips in there are .wav alrdy. But I can render the video and audio as .flac and not .wav in render options....or i can just combine after with vlc or something else

Comment: Also check that your User Preferences are using SDL for Sequencer Audio Device.

Comment: it was set to Open AL, I'll try SDL then.

Comment: Generally .wav is the more stable format to use.

Comment: Hey if any of this was helpful I'll put it in an answer ;-)

Comment: Also you must understand that Blender is not a proper mixing tool. It has no reference levels or meters, so you cannot know what level you are mixing to. It may be to hot and distorted, but you can't know. Audacity is better for this stuff.

Comment: SDL didn't do anything after running my tests. I'm still unable to get it to sound like the way it is in the sequencer . But changing the accuracy to 1 helps alot of it sound better, not all of it tho.....so problem still outstanding. If I can't find another fix I'll have to do the audacity capture method.

Comment: It may be worth submitting a bug on the blender bug tracker if you can figure out the point which blender fails. You said that it worked with a smaller file is that right?

Comment: Meta tip: If you amend your question with an update, please add a date so return helpers can figure out what's new.

Comment: I had issues with an older version of blender in the past (sound mixing timing problem), and there was a bug fix for Blender 2.79. Perhaps you could download a newer version of Blender (eg. 2.79a or b). Alternatively try going back to an older version of Blender that may not have the bug.

Comment: Just wondering what OS you are running on and what audio drivers you may be using?

Comment: My problem seems to be blender is mixing audio at a volume different than what I hear in the VSE playback. So if I hit N on a strip and set the volume to 10, it may sound barely audible to me depending on my sound settings. But for blender the waveform is maxed and clipping at that point. Setting it back to 1 makes the waveform not clip though. So to use mixdown I have to figure out a way to hear it the same volume that it renders at. With basic rendering I can adjust the mastervolume scale from 1 or 0.01 or whatever, to decrease the amp. This method seems to have its own problems tho

Comment: Oh dear that really was a lot of work. I just exported a VSE edit yesterday with mixed audio sources and had no problem. I really think that you should try older builds of Blender and alternate projects. Just to isolate a possible bug. The other thing to try is making another VSE scene (Scene MIXDOWN), then import the main edited scene (Scene EDIT) as a scene strip. You can then modify the sequencer audio from that Mixdown scene as a single strip.

Comment: Hey I just read this other stackx query I wonder if its related? Have you tried an AAC export? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73017/how-do-i-export-audio-in-a-video-that-is-purposefully-loud-and-distorted-vse

Comment: Also just check that you don't have other sync scenes running?https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75546/double-instance-of-sound-when-using-vse-scene-strip-in-another-scenes-vse

Comment: i've tried rendering it with AAC as the audio setting yes; - I went to the top where my current scene is (I only had one), and hit the plus to add a new scene. Then I ctrl+c'd the audio strips in picture 2 and ctrl+v'd them into the second scene. Then I deleted the first scene. Upon testing playback tho it played an audio strip that wasn't visible. I had appended a scene in I did in a separate .blend file from a 20 min video a while ago. For some reason its playing its audio in this new scene ijustmade. Keyframes are also missing when I ctrl+c into the new scene (idk how to fix). rly weird

Comment: Yeah I don't believe that you can copy keyframes between scenes, sorry. What operating system are you using? Did you try making just an empty scene and adding the main edit to it as a scene strip? You should be able to reduce the overall volume that way much easier (as a workaround)

Comment: windows8.1 ; that might work as a workaround. It just has the audio in the scene, no video output. But ur right its letting me change the overall volume, so I can mixdown at a lower volume now. ill try mixing that down.

Comment: Just a heads up, there was an old audio bug related to windows 8, https://developer.blender.org/T37432 and some reference to pops and crackles in audio when overlapped. Could give the appearance of excess volume?

Comment: Just a query but have you tried an Audio Mixdown instead of a movie render out?

Comment: When I say mixdown I mean hitting the Audio tab under property render options, and then selecting mixdown and creating just the audio track.  developer.blender.org/T37432 I don't think that applies in this case, or I don't understand it. I was able to mixdown afterall using ur scene method, setting the audio from 1 to 0.1, it prevented the clipping/distortion while preventing any audio strips with keyframes from missing (the problem with normal render). So this is a solution, then you just amplify in audacity or whatever after. I'll add urs as the answer if bug report yields nothing. thxs

Comment: This all sucks. Before lodging a bug report can you try to recreate the issue with another new project? It doesn't have to be elaborate just a bunch of overlapping media. As small as possible, so that you could upload the .blend and media as a test project. That way I can try it on a PC and a Mac.And you could try it on an older version of Blender. This would help narrow the issue down

Comment: There's a blend file up there already. You should be able to recreate the clipping issue urself with any audio strip. Use factory blender user settings in a new .blend. Open the VSE. Insert a medium->large waveform audio piece (draw waveform) (voiceovers work best). Duplicate it, raise the duplicate's volume to 10.0 or higher. Listen to it in vse playback (one should sound louder, otherwise they should both sound clear/fine). mixdown. You should get similar waveform as I have in figure1.  Amplifying the broken waveform down to the normal one, it should remain visibly damaged by the clipping.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that Blender is doing some sort of clamping of audio values on output. I can imagine that Blender can play a hotter signal than the exported codec can cope with.

Comment: Took me a while to get this to play, but have you tried changing the system>properties>Sound>Mixing Buffer>256  and change the sample rate to 48k

Comment: The volume= 10 strip is over modulating and I'm not surprised its burning out the encoding math. Also the sample media is very low level even on other media players on my mac. I would put a lot of this down to you not being able to balance your system audio. And thats an issue with Blender's lack of audio monitoring meters. you should be able to play a signal and determine the optimum loudness with overhead for hot signal. But you can't, as there are no audio meters in Blender.

Comment: system property sound options were tried a while ago, no difference in terms of the clipping. Ya it seems to come down to planning ahead and pre-editing all audio strips beforehand in audacity....so when they are finally put into blender I only have to change the volume levels between 0.0 - 2.0. Then tinkering with my own sound settings to make 1.0 sound like the middle of a waveform. I'm not overly fond of having to do extra steps like this though....not when the playback lying to me.

Comment: I must say I've never had this much trouble even when using very low recordings

Comment: I mean I've done Four projects in blender so far (AMV). So its literally music playing to scenes, and I've had some voice audio strips included on some of them. So maybe up to 8 audio strips per 6 mins of video. Yet I never noticed this problem during any of those 4 projects. Its just now on this very large project with many strip that I notice it.

Comment: Like you say, it could be related to Blender's handling of many strips, especially overlapping ones. I wonder what would happen if you break the big mix into smaller scenes. Making each one only a few minutes long? Then compile them into a master scene? Also it could be that your project is broken. Is there any way you could rebuild a basic (but still long) version without the trouble of doing the mixing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround (to an apparent bug) you can send the "mixed" scene to another VSE timeline using a scene strip. In the new "master" Scene the old "mixed" scene's strip will allow you to make a global change to volume. But you will have to enable the button "Use Sequencer" in the scene strip properties.

[image: scene strip volume properties]

Then you can bring the volume down to a value that won't distort or clip.

You will have to render from this new "master" scene.